# How to center and wrap text inside node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

Consider two circles with long text nodes inside:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm) node[text width=3cm] {This is a relatively long text};
    \draw (5,0) circle (1.5cm) node[text width=3cm] {This is another very long text};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to have the text centered and wrapped in each circle. I've tried two solutions so far:

1. Using `label=center:<my_text>` inside `node`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210713/node-positioned-by-fit-how-to-center-a-node-text). This centers the text, but does not wrap it. So the text goes outside the circle.
2. Using `pos=0.5` or `midway` inside `node`, as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96340/how-to-place-a-textnode-at-the-center-of-a-drawn-rectangle). This works fine for one circle, but not for two. The text is placed on top of each other in the first circle.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Just add `align=center` to the node options.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to make the node circle shapes, add `align=center` to the text, and given them a minimum size.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)% circle (1.5cm) 
    node[align=center,minimum size=3cm,draw,circle] 
    {This is\\ a relatively\\ long text};
    \draw (5,0)% circle (1.5cm) 
    node[align=center,minimum size=3cm,draw,circle] 
    {This is\\ another very\\ long text};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You need to add the line breaks yourself, or use something like `parshape` to automatically follow the outline of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment inside nodes is determined by the `align` key. In this case you want `align=center`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm) node[text width=3cm,align=center] {This is a relatively long text};
    \draw (5,0) circle (1.5cm) node[text width=3cm,align=center] {This is another very long text};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]